# Restoring an NPC's Mind

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques

So in my campaign, one of the PC's is trying to find out about the origins of their magic crystal. They've been led to one of the High Priests in the city, but he has lost his mind, through deceit and being lured in to a trap by something/someone. His body is still functional, but for all intents and purposes he has no intelligence whatsoever.

My question is, are there any spells or monsters (other than an intellect devourer) that could essentially take someone's mind/conciousness and store it somewhere, say in a soul gem?

Comment: Is the "storing" a necessity?

Comment: @Momonga-sama it would be helpful, as I planned for them to restore his mind so he can help out with their quest, plus another side quest will come into play - but if not I'm sure he could've made plenty of notes about things before the incident!

Comment: This isn't quite what you're looking for, so I don't think I should post it as an answer, but does it have to be something that exists mechanically? You can always create a plot device for it.

Comment: @Fibericon not necessarily but it would be nice to at least have a spell or mechanic that traps a person's mind or soul - the container could easily be a simple magic item that I can create :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Feeble mind

This spell simply drops one's Inteligence to mere 1. There is no trapping soul unfortunately.

## Imprisonment

Slumber. The Highpriest will be asleep.

**Clone** + **Minimus containment**
The highpriest, that they have seen is just a vessel. The real one is trapped inside a gem.

You could modify **Minimus containment**, it is powerful enough to trap someone's entire body in a gem.

All of the mentioned possibilities will be maintained until someone uses dispell magic as 9th level spell. Finding someone who can cast 9th level spells could be an adventure itself.

## Magic jar

The highpriest has been tricked into casting Magic Jar spell. Shortly after his soul would be imprisoned in a soulgem, the deceiver would place it in an antimagic chest or something like that. Also it could be put into an isolated place (no living forms in 100 feet radius). (When the players will try to get the gem, the highpriest could possess one of them. That would be a nice plottwist.)

Comment: Would "possessing a PC" mean that the player can't participate in the game anymore because all actions of their PC are now controlled by the NPC and by extension the DM? If so think twice if you really want to do it, as it makes the rest of the game quite boring for the player. But maybe you can find some way to do it in a way that player-agency is preserved.

Comment: @Philipp Simple dispell would "kick out" the intruder. Furthermore if I understand correctly, the highpriest isn't a bad person, thus I doubt that he'd take over one's body permamently.

Comment: @Philipp my thinking would be that he doesn't fully possess the PC, more the fact that the PC would now have an extra voice inside their head, perhaps guiding their actions a little!